# Javascript assign variable to an object field with name starting with a digit

Tags: javascript

I am running an external API that return a response with one field called 3DSecureId
i try to set this field to a variable as below

```
const SecureId =  apiResponse.3DSecureId
```

I get the following error
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

can someone help
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
const SecureId = apiResponse['3DSecureId']
```